# Why is ArgumentParser add_argument not picking up this argument?

Tags: python, argparse

I have the following code at the top of my class:

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,
                help="path to input image")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--method", required=False, default="CAFFE",
                help="Method")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

input_image_path = args["image"]
detection_method = args["method"]
```

When I try to run with these parameters, I get the error shown here:

```
python FaceRecognition.py -i images//test_image.jpg -m "CAFFE"
usage: FaceRecognition.py [-h] [-m METHOD]
FaceRecognition.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -i images//test_image.jpg
```

Why does it not recognise the -i argument?

I've already tried adding quotes, changing the order of the arguments, removing the other argument.

I tried running this:

```
python FaceRecognition.py -m "CAFFE"
usage: FaceRecognition.py [-h] -i IMAGE [-m METHOD]
FaceRecognition.py: error: the following arguments are required: -i/--image
```

How come it only recognises it when I dont include it?

Comment: Hey have you tried just doing args = ap.parse_args()? The vars should not be necessary. Also, please run this and see what you get: python FaceRecognition.py --help

Comment: Hey, okay I just copy pasted your code as is and, well it's working for me. No problems...

Comment: @Neil I tried removing the vars and no change. 

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe D:/FaceRecognition2/FaceRecognition.py -h
usage: FaceRecognition.py [-h] [-m METHOD]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -m METHOD, --method METHOD
                        method for face detection (HAAR/CAFFE)

```

Comment: I think you need to post your full module. If I take this code, add "import argparse", then it works.

Comment: Do you have two versions of thia parser in your script?  The errors have different usage messages.

Comment: Good spot @hpaulj What is worrying me is that OP say "at the top of my class". Probably they have 2 classes in one module each with their own parser...

Comment: @Neil
That's what it was haha. My script calls another script which requires arguments. 
I forgot to include the arguments for this other script (and I don't really know how, but that's a separate issue lol)
Thanks for pointing that out